# Is this definition of the closure of a set circular?

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X,\mathcal{T})$ be a set and collection of open sets forming a topology on $X$.  For $A\subset X$ we define the closure of $A$, as 
$$
\overline{A} = \bigcap_{F\ \mathrm{is\ closed};\, F\supset A} F.
$$

This is a definition I have seen more than once.  My puzzlement is that if we assume this definition is proper, then one of the $F$'s turns out to be the closure of $A$.  So in a sense $\overline{A}$ appears on both sides of the equal sign in a definition.  I am sure I haven't found some paradox in topology so can someone correct my misunderstanding?

Comment: For the definition, we don't use that $\overline{A}$ is one of the sets whose intersection we take. For any family $\mathscr{F}$ of closed sets we can define $B(\mathscr{F}) := \bigcap\limits_{F\in \mathscr{F}} F$. Generally, $B(\mathscr{F})$ is not an element of $\mathscr{F}$. Sometimes it is, but that is incidental.

Comment: My understanding of the definition, though, is that intersection is taken over all closed sets that contain $A$.   The emphasis on the word "all".

Comment: Yes. But it is not part of the definition that there is in fact a smallest such set, that's just a consequence of the fact that any intersection of closed sets is closed.

Comment: You define closed without mentioning closures at all. If you can decide if a set is closed or not without recurring to closures then you can use specification. See my answer .

Comment: To define a closure, we only need to talk about closed sets that contain certain set. We never talk about closure itself when defining closure (other than, well, calling it "closure"), so it's not circular. It's just that it can happen that thus defined closure is a member used to define closure, but before we defined closure it didn't have any other properties other than it being just a closed set.

Comment: I am awarding a prize to the funniest person in the world. But wait how can I do that? To identify the funniest person, I first have to look at the set of all people, one of whom is the funniest. But isn't that circular? Obviously not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not circular at all. The power set of $X$ exists by the Axiom of Powers, you are taking the intersection of the family $\{F \in \mathscr{P}(X): F \text{ is closed }, F \supset A\}$ which is again a set by the Axiom of Specification. This set is not empty since $X$ is closed. Note that we never mentioned closures here, you can decide if a set is closed or not simply by inspecting $\tau$.

If you are not comfortable enough with this amount of set theory I would recommend you read some set theory book before attempting to study Topology. I recommend Naive Set Theory from Halmos (the first 30 or so pages are more relevant in this case).

Comment: I actually disagree with this answer in the sense that I do not believe that the answer here lies in retreating right back to axioms. An intuitive understanding of what is going on is hugely important and will take you a lot further than simply saying it must be ok because an axiom says so. Your original question was a sensible one and has a sensible answer which I tried to outline in my own answer. Understanding axioms is very important but you need to really get a feel for what's actually happening when you are applying them.

Comment: First, OP never mentioned the definition of the closure as the smallest closed set which contains $A$. The question was if the definition, using intersections, is circular if the set itself is in the family. The motivation for the definition is another question altogether. The proper way of showing it is not circular needs some rigor, intuition could be misleading.

Answer (score 2):

No it is not. We know what closed sets are (complements of open sets), and that they are closed under arbitrary intersection. So the right hand side is just a special closed set $C$, and is well-defined. Just from the axioms.

The way we made it, ensures that *every* closed set $C'$ that contains $A$ (there is at least one, namely $X$) is in the family we take an intersection of, so $C \subseteq C'$ for all such $C'$.

So it is the minimal closed set that contains $A$ (this is what the previous paragraph means). So this is a well-defined set, we can just define from $A$ and the topology alone. So we can call it $f(A)$ or, as is usual, $\overline{A}$ (sometimes $\operatorname{Cl}(A)$ as well).

We do *not* assume the closure is well-defined. We show it is well-defined from the axioms and then introduce a notation for it, as it turns out to be a useful set to consider in relation to $A$.

Answer (score 2):

The above definition for $\bar{A}$ is essentially saying that $\bar{A}$ is the $\textbf{smallest}$ closed set which contains A. But for sets which don't have any sort of measurable structure on them (and may have infinite or uncountably infinite numbers of members) how do we understand the notion of $\textbf{smallest}$?

The above definition describes how to construct this smallest closed set and so this is defining what we mean by smallest in this context. You are absolutely right that $\bar{A}$ will be one of these closed sets, but we won't know which one until we have taken the intersection of $\textbf{all}$ of the possible closed sets, what we are left with is then the closure of A,  $\bar{A}$.

Without going through the process of taking all intersection we can't possibly know which closed set is indeed the closure we are looking for.